# Interface for 2 classes of same super class in Java

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, types, interface

Is there a way to write an interface whose method gets implemented by classes with the same super class? What I tried was using generic methods.

```
class person{
    private String name;
    //getter and setter
    .
}


class Student extends Person{
    private int points;
    //getter and setter
    .
}

class Worker extends Person{
    private int salary;
    //getter and setter
    .
}

interface Printer{
    <T extends Person> void print (T person);   
}

class WorkerPrinter implements Printer {

    @Override
    public <T extends Person> void print(T person) {
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        System.out.println(person.getSalary());
    }
}
```

The compiler cannot resolve `person.getSalary()` even though the generic type T extends from `Person`.

I want to use this interface in a similar way with a class `StudentPrinter` and the implemented Method `print(T Person)`

So basicly what I want is to use the Interface for different "printerclasses" which are inheriting from `Person`. This is just an example of course. I want to use this in a bigger example. Is this somehow possible? Does it even make sense?

Comment: What would you expect to happen if you called `new WorkerPrinter().print(new Student())`? I believe you should make `Printer` generic *as an interface* rather than having a generic method - so `WorkerPrinter` would implement `Printer<Worker>`.

Comment: Declare your Print method as an `abstract` method in Person.  This will require implementers of classes extending Person to override the Print method, and the correct Print method will be called automatically via runtime polymorphism.

Comment: You can make your code work by simply doing a case distinction for the type of person and then cast it correspondingly:
`if (person instanceof Worker) {System.out.println(((Worker)person).getSalary());}`
and so on. I'm not posting this as an answer, as it's not very elegant and as it's also not clear to me whether this is the kind of solution you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jon Skeet already suggested (that's why I made this answer a community wiki answer, so feel free to improve further), you might want to make your interface have a generic type parameter T instead of having only a method with generic argument type T. Then you could write:

```
interface Printer<T extends Person> {
    void print (T person);   
}

class WorkerPrinter implements Printer<Worker> {

    @Override
    public void print(Worker person) {
        System.out.println(person.getName());
        System.out.println(person.getSalary());
    }
}
```